# How to sort based on keyword?

Tags: perl, sorting, sed, awk

How can I can sort based on a key word? I have a kind-of complicated list and am wondering if I can sort it. Here is an example:

```
enter code here Room Name: RM145 
                ,ID,user Name
                ,300,NOS
                ,100,NOT
                Room Name: RM370 
                ,ID,user Name
                ,300,NOS
                Room Name: RM471  
                ,ID,user Name
                ,300,POS
                ,100,NOT
                Room Name: RM349  
                ,ID,user Name
                ,301,NOS
                ,100,NOT
                ,500,COS
```

My objective is to sort this list based on "`Room Name`".

I have the file in both plain text and CSV. I don't know which one is will be easier to sort. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *GNU awk 4*:

```
awk 'END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
  for (R in r)
    print r[R]
  }
/Room Name:/ {
  rn = substr($NF, 3)
  }
{
  r[rn] = r[rn] ? r[rn] ORS $0 : $0
  }' infile
```

This one should work with older *GNU awk* versions:

```
WHINY_USERS=  awk 'END {
  for (R in r)
    print r[R]
  }
/Room Name:/ {
  rn = sprintf("%15s", substr($NF, 3))
  }
{
  r[rn] = r[rn] ? r[rn] ORS $0 : $0
  }' infile
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, this will not work as expected if the first Room Name is not the lowest value.

Comment: Hi @Chris, you're right, thanks! It will not work at all if the input needs to be sorted numerically by the trailing digits of the room name (if I understand your comments correctly). I've corrected the script.

Comment: thanks for your response, Unfortunately I have awk version 3, I don't have admin right to update software. didn't work on my current version thanks much anyways!!

Comment: Hi @eli1128, I've added a modified version that should work with older *GNU awk* versions (it won't work with *GNU awk 4*!). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Dimitre, you are the man! honestly I was undermine the ability of awk. you proved me wrong!! it's working perfectly. thanks a lot!!! I am really appreciated your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the sort key is the room name you could do :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %room_by;
my $roomname;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( m/Room Name:\s*(.+)/ ) {
        $roomname = $1;
        $room_by{$roomname} = ();
    }
    else {
        push @{$room_by{$roomname}}, $_;
    }
}
for $roomname (sort keys %room_by) {
    print "Room Name: $roomname\n";
    for my $content ( @{$room_by{$roomname}} ) {
        print "$content\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
Room Name: RM145 
,ID,user Name
,300,NOS
,100,NOT
Room Name: RM370 
,ID,user Name
,300,NOS
Room Name: RM471  
,ID,user Name
,300,POS
,100,NOT
Room Name: RM349  
,ID,user Name
,301,NOS
,100,NOT
,500,COS
```

This collects the room names in a hash of arrays where the hash key is the room name and the hash values are the contents of the rooms.  You could also sort the hash values to order those too.

Comment: wow! it's working perfectly. I am really jealous on your knowledge. how you quickly come up with this solution. thank you so very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can format your file such that each record is on its own line, this is pretty trivial with `sort`

```
$ cat ./infile
Room Name: RM145,ID,user Name,300,NOS,100,NOT
Room Name: RM370,ID,user Name,300,NOS
Room Name: RM471,ID,user Name,300,POS,100,NOT
Room Name: RM349,ID,user Name,301,NOS,100,NOT,500,COS

$ sort ./infile
Room Name: RM145,ID,user Name,300,NOS,100,NOT
Room Name: RM349,ID,user Name,301,NOS,100,NOT,500,COS
Room Name: RM370,ID,user Name,300,NOS
Room Name: RM471,ID,user Name,300,POS,100,NOT
```